# html nsted tab not opening - Uncaught typeERror: Cannot read property 'Style' of null

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a web page with tabbed interface. The script to open the tabs work fine for the tabs declared in the page. But if I tried to declare nested tabs, tabs within a tab, the script doesn't open the nested tab.

The page shows the error

> Uncaught typeERror: Cannot read property 'Style' of null

The errors appear on line:

```
document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";//Error
```

&

```
<button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'tab6')">tab6</button> //error
```

Here is a minimal code:

```js
    function openCity(evt, cityName) {
        var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
        tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
        for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
            tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
        for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
            tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
        evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
    }
```

```html
<div class="tab">
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'tab1')">tab1</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'tab2')">tab2</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'tab3')">tab3</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'tab4')">tab4</button>
    </div>
    
    <div id="tab1" class="tabcontent">
    </div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tabcontent">
    </div>
    <div id="tab3" class="tabcontent">
       <div class="tab">
            <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'tab5')">tab5</button>
            <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'tab6')">tab6</button> //error
       </div> 
    <div id="tab5" class="tabcontent">
    </div>
    
    
</div>
```

Comment: It clearly says that there is no such control who's `id = tab6`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have any elements with id-s `tab4` nor `tab6` so ofcourse it will return undefined

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
        var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
        tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
        for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
            tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
        for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
            tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
        evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
    }
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'tab1')">tab1</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'tab2')">tab2</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'tab3')">tab3</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'tab4')">tab4</button>
</div>

<div id="tab1" class="tabcontent">
</div>
<div id="tab2" class="tabcontent">
</div>
<div id="tab3" class="tabcontent">
  <div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'tab5')">tab5</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'tab6')">tab6</button> //error
  </div>
</div>
<div id="tab5" class="tabcontent"></div>
<div id="tab6" class="tabcontent"> added tab6</div>
<div id="tab4" class="tabcontent">added tab4</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because some tab ids are missing
For instance.

```
 <div id="tab6" class="tabcontent">
```

Thus, `getElementById` is getting an `undefined` element

Answer (score 0):

It happen because you send `tab6` as `cityName` and there is **no** id calls `tab6`

**Your options:**

1. Add `<div id="tab6" class="tabcontent">`
2. Ask if `id` is exist before set style `if(document.getElementById(cityName)!=undefind)`

```js
    function openCity(evt, cityName) {
        var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
        tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
        for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
            tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
        for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
            tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
//option 2
if(document.getElementById(cityName)!=undefind)
        document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
        evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
    }
```

```html
<div class="tab">
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'tab1')">tab1</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'tab2')">tab2</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'tab3')">tab3</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'tab4')">tab4</button>
    </div>
    
    <div id="tab1" class="tabcontent">
    </div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tabcontent">
    </div>
    <div id="tab3" class="tabcontent">
       <div class="tab">
            <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'tab5')">tab5</button>
            <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'tab6')">tab6</button> //error
       </div> 
    <div id="tab5" class="tabcontent">
<!-- option 1 -->
    <div id="tab6" class="tabcontent">
    </div>
    
    
</div>
```